# How to remove the Parent reference from a Customer Record using Web service in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

In Netsuite, using Webservice, How can I remove the parent reference of a customer.

The following doesn't work

```
<listRel:parent externalId="" xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2012_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use null field list.

See this for instructions:

http://www.daveweiss.net/2013/04/setting-fields-to-null-with-netsuite-web-services/

Comment: <platformCore:nullFieldList xsi:type="platformCore:NullField" xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2012_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
                    <platformCore:name>parent</platformCore:name>
                   </platformCore:nullFieldList>

Comment: Hey - sorry my link was a bit messed up. I fixed it. Anyway, there is full code there to show you how it's done.